# Correct (?) regex not understood by sed

Tags: regex, sed

According to https://regex101.com/r/NLSymf/3, the following regex:

```
\[\[(foo)([^\]]+)\]\]
```

(full) matches the string `[[foo>test1|test2]]`, but this seems to not be understood by `sed`, since:

```
echo "[[foo>test1|test2]]" | sed -E -e '/\[\[(foo)([^\]]+)\]\]/d'
```

(which should return an empty string) returns:

```
[[foo>test1|test2]]
```

What is the regex that matches `[[foo>test1|test2]]` from `sed`'s point of view?

Comment: To match `[[foo>test1|test2]]` in sed use `sed '/\[\[foo>test1|test2\]\]/d' <<<' [[foo>test1|test2]]'` i.e. just escape the `[` and `]` metacharacters, there is no need to group `foo` and the remainder is pattern matched character for character.

Comment: @potong I should have mentioned, in my real use case, I need the groups for backreferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash character loses its escaping capability within a bracket expression. And stray closing brackets in a RE need not be escaped, that's why grep doesn't fail the first pipeline below. See [RE Bracket Expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) for reference.

```
$ echo 'a]' | grep -Eo '[^\]]'
a]
$ echo 'a]' | grep -Eo '[^]]'
a
```

The **correct** regex would be:

```
\[\[(foo)([^]]+)]]
```